# Vue.js 2/Vuex - How to call getters from modules that has attribute namespaced:true without mapGetters?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

This is my module:

```
const ModuleA={
   namespaced:true,
   state:{
      categoryList:[
         {name:'all', isActive:true},
         {name:'negotiation', isActive:false},
      ]
   },
   getters:{
      getCategory:(state)=>(index)=>{
        return state.categoryList[index];
      },
   }
}
```

Without `namespaced:true`, I can call `getCategory` with `this.$store.getters.getCategory(this.index)`.

How to call `getCategory` with `namespaced:true`? I can't use `mapGetters` because I have to pass parameter to the function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See 2nd answer to this [How to access Vuex module getters and mutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833424/how-to-access-vuex-module-getters-and-mutations)

```
this.$store.getters['ModuleA/getCategory'](this.index)
```

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much! I saw that post before but wasn't expecting that to work with params.