# How to retrieve data from a specific getters in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

How to retrieve data from a specific getters in vue?

this.$store.getters('client/list'))

TypeError: _this.$store.getters is not a function
    at eval (Login2.vue?3936:64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Set the getter in the store.

```
getters: {
     clientList: state => {
          return state.clientList
     }
}
```

Step 2: Call the getter in your component as computed

```
computed: {
   clientList () {
          return this.$store.getters.clientList
     }
}
```

Check your syntax. The getter you posted won't work because you're missing the module-specific syntax.

As an example from the following link:
`this.$store.getters['ModuleA/getCategory'](this.index)`

See more here: [Vue.js 2/Vuex - How to call getters from modules that has attribute namespaced:true without mapGetters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47327388/vue-js-2-vuex-how-to-call-getters-from-modules-that-has-attribute-namespacedt)

Comment: Hi @Arc, I was wondering if you could take a second look at my post, to which you responded a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59200408/how-to-retrieve-currentuser-data-with-vue-js-vuex-express-mongodb/59205423#59205423 . I tried adding the ```vuex-persist``` plugin to the store.js file, like you recommended. I am not sure how else to configure this plugin in order to persist. any recommendations?