# How pass state vuex on created()

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have been using vuex for a project for a few days now. Now I need to pass the value of a state to the created method.
Below I show the code used.

**Store file**

```
state: {
     friendstatus: null 

},
mutations: {
SET_FRIEND_STATUS: (state,friend) => {
  state.friendstatus = data;
},
actions: {
getFriendStatus: ({commit},data) => {
  //axios request returns friendstatus
commit('STATE_FRIEND_STATUS',response.data.status)
}
```

**Vue component**

```
computed: {
...mapstate('friend',['friendstatus'])
},
created() {
//Here I need to pass friendstatus. Obviously if I call this.friendstatus it does not work. 
 this.$store.dispatch('friend/getFriendStatus);// I would like to call the state and not the action 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access Vuex module getters and mutations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833424/how-to-access-vuex-module-getters-and-mutations)

Comment: Thanks it works!